# How do you fix the indentations of a text file when you see a { or }?

Tags: java, file, if-statement, while-loop

My code takes a text file that has code in it and when it sees a {, it increases indentation by 4 and when it sees a }, it decreases indentation by 4.  My problem I'm having is that when a double brace pops(}} or {{) or when a line has two ();.  I'm haven't been able to successfully separate them and print them on the next line with the right indentations.

```
public static void face (Scanner File){
      int spacect = 0;
      while (File.hasNextLine()) {
        String w = File.nextLine();
        String a = w.trim();
        if(a.contains(})){
            spacect-=4;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<spacect;i++){
            System.out.print(space);
        }   
        if(a.contains({)){
            spacect+=4;
        }
}
```

---

an example file input would be:

```
public static void sound (String t, PrintStream output){
Scanner d = new Scanner(t);
if(d.hasNext())
{
output.print(d.hasNext());
while (d.hasNext()){
                output.print(" " + d.next();}}
        output.println(); d.close();
        }
```

The correct output should be:

```
public static void sound (String t, PrintStream output){
    Scanner d = new Scanner(t);
    if(d.hasNext()){
        output.print(d.hasNext());
        while (d.hasNext()){
            output.print(" " + d.next();
        }
    }
    output.println(); 
    d.close();
 }
```

Comment: What about single line if statements without braces? Do you handle that indentation? Basically, there are several small edge cases that a simple `contains("{")` may not catch.

Comment: How do you want to indent a double opening brace?

Comment: @shmoosel if there is an double opening brace, the indentation would increase by 8

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your use of `String.contains("}")` and `String.contains("{")`.  If you have a string with `{{` that will register the same as a string with just `{` and same for `}}` and `}`.  That's because `String.contains()` is only telling you if that character is contained.  If the character is repeated it still just says `true`.  So your current code has no clue if there are multiple braces on a line.

You will need to do something like iterating through the string and changing the indent level each time you see a `{` or a `}`.

Comment: so by doing a  String.contains("}}"), that would fix that problem if it had two braces.  But how would I, after reading that it has  two braces in a line, fix the indentation as the two } need to be on their own separate line for correct indentation?